# Vsts Xamarin ios Build Ios Certificate

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have problem when i try to build my ios solution with Xamarin.Ios Build. I have this error :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(635,3): error : No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile '09c40a99-c785-4410-a9bd-b161c511eb92'.
```

I don't know how to found the certificate Corresponding to ID. Any one can help me for found solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your app in real device. You should add provisioning profile and signing certificate corresponding to your project's bundle ID.

### Solution1:

You can create this files and download in [Apple's developer site](http://developer.apple.com). Then configure it in your VS: **Double click your project -> iOS Bundle Signing** like:
[image]

### Solution2:

You can also use automatic signing in info.plist. Add your account team first then check on the automatically manage signing.

Answer (score 0):

`09c40a99-c785-4410-a9bd-b161c511eb92` is the ID of the provisioning profile.  The easiest way to find which certificates are associated with that profile is to install [this](https://github.com/chockenberry/Provisioning) excellent QuickLook plugin.  Once you've installed it you can inspect any .mobileprovision file.  Halfway down it shows the certificates.

If you don't have the .mobileprovision file you can go to the provisioning profile area of the Apple Developer Portal [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/), click on the profile you're using and click the Edit button.

If you're using a development provisioning profile then it'll list all of the development certificates and if it's a distribution profile then it'll show the single distribution certificate.

Hope that helps,

Paul